# How do I align/position text next to my menu toggle button

Tags: html, css

I've got a script that creates a great mobile friendly menu.

I'd like to position some text next to the toggle button.

Not sure where to start, I've tried to add the text before and after the nav tag. Struggling to figure out how to position the text inside the nav

[image: How my menu looks]

```
[JSFiddle Code][2]
```

https://jsfiddle.net/85p3m6cr/

Comment: Did you consider that, *maybe*, the warning about including code was there for a reason? You should be pasting your code *in your question body*, not putting a jsfiddle link in a code block.

Comment: I did consider it, but there's a lot of code

Comment: In that case, you should read [how to best ask questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<nav id="nav" role="navigation">
  <a href="#nav" title="Show navigation">Show navigation</a>
  <a href="#" title="Hide navigation">Hide navigation</a>
  <ul class="clearfix">
  <li><a href="http://www.google.co.uk" target="new">Item 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
  </ul>
    <div class="text-style">
        Text here
    </div>

  </nav>
```

CSS

```
   .text-style {
  position: absolute;
  top: 7px;
  left: 45px;
}

a {
text-decoration: none;
}
ul, li {
list-style: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
#nav {
width: 60em; /* 1000 */
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
font-weight: 400;
position: absolute;
top: 25%;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -30em; /* 30 480 */
}
#nav > a {
display: none;
}
#nav li {
position: relative;
}
#nav li a {
color: #fff;
display: block;
}
#nav li a:active {
background-color: #c00 !important;
}
#nav span:after {
width: 0;
height: 0;
border: 0.313em solid transparent; /* 5 */
border-bottom: none;
border-top-color: #efa585;
content: '';
vertical-align: middle;
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
right: -0.313em; /* 5 */
}
/* first level */

#nav > ul {
height: 3.75em; /* 60 */
background-color: #e15a1f;
}
#nav > ul > li {
width: 25%;
height: 100%;
float: left;
}
#nav > ul > li > a {
height: 100%;
font-size: 1.5em; /* 24 */
line-height: 2.5em; /* 60 (24) */
text-align: center;
}
#nav > ul > li:not( :last-child ) > a {
border-right: 1px solid #cc470d;
}
#nav > ul > li:hover > a, #nav > ul:not( :hover ) > li.active > a {
background-color: #cc470d;
}
/* second level */

#nav li ul {
background-color: #cc470d;
display: none;
position: absolute;
top: 100%;
}
#nav li:hover ul {
display: block;
left: 0;
right: 0;
}
#nav li:not( :first-child ):hover ul {
left: -1px;
}
#nav li ul a {
font-size: 1.25em; /* 20 */
border-top: 1px solid #e15a1f;
padding: 0.75em; /* 15 (20) */
}
#nav li ul li a:hover, #nav li ul:not( :hover ) li.active a {
background-color: #e15a1f;
}
 @media only screen and ( max-width: 62.5em ) /* 1000 */ {
#nav {
width: 100%;
position: static;
margin: 0;
}
}
 @media only screen and ( max-width: 40em ) /* 640 */ {
html {
font-size: 75%; /* 12 */
}
#nav {
position: relative;
top: auto;
left: auto;
}
#nav > a {
width: 3.125em; /* 50 */
height: 3.125em; /* 50 */
text-align: left;
text-indent: -9999px;
background-color: #e15a1f;
position: relative;
}
#nav > a:before, #nav > a:after {
position: absolute;
border: 2px solid #fff;
top: 35%;
left: 25%;
right: 25%;
content: '';
}
#nav > a:after {
top: 60%;
}
#nav:not( :target ) > a:first-of-type, #nav:target > a:last-of-type {
display: block;
}
/* first level */

#nav > ul {
height: auto;
display: none;
position: absolute;
left: 0;
right: 0;
}
#nav:target > ul {
display: block;
}
#nav > ul > li {
width: 100%;
float: none;
}
#nav > ul > li > a {
height: auto;
text-align: left;
padding: 0 0.833em; /* 20 (24) */
}
#nav > ul > li:not( :last-child ) > a {
border-right: none;
border-bottom: 1px solid #cc470d;
}
/* second level */

#nav li ul {
position: static;
padding: 1.25em; /* 20 */
padding-top: 0;
}
```

Comment: I hope this is what you need.

Comment: Thank you Aakash, that is exactly what I needed. Thank you for your constructive help. Cheers John

Answer (score 1):

I would use the `:before` attr and add it when the menu breaks so it only displays at the correct time needed.

```
 #nav:before {
        content:"TEXT HERE";
        position: absolute;
        left: 3.5em;
        top: 50%;
        transform: translateY(-50%);
    }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/85p3m6cr/10/

```js
$(function () {
    $('#nav li:has(ul)').doubleTapToGo();
});
```

```css
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
ul, li {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#nav {
    width: 60em;
    /* 1000 */
    font-family:'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    position: absolute;
    top: 25%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -30em;
    /* 30 480 */
}
#nav > a {
    display: none;
}
#nav li {
    position: relative;
}
#nav li a {
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
}
#nav li a:active {
    background-color: #c00 !important;
}
#nav span:after {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border: 0.313em solid transparent;
    /* 5 */
    border-bottom: none;
    border-top-color: #efa585;
    content:'';
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    right: -0.313em;
    /* 5 */
}
/* first level */
 #nav > ul {
    height: 3.75em;
    /* 60 */
    background-color: #e15a1f;
}
#nav > ul > li {
    width: 25%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
}
#nav > ul > li > a {
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    /* 24 */
    line-height: 2.5em;
    /* 60 (24) */
    text-align: center;
}
#nav > ul > li:not(:last-child) > a {
    border-right: 1px solid #cc470d;
}
#nav > ul > li:hover > a, #nav > ul:not(:hover) > li.active > a {
    background-color: #cc470d;
}
/* second level */
 #nav li ul {
    background-color: #cc470d;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
}
#nav li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
#nav li:not(:first-child):hover ul {
    left: -1px;
}
#nav li ul a {
    font-size: 1.25em;
    /* 20 */
    border-top: 1px solid #e15a1f;
    padding: 0.75em;
    /* 15 (20) */
}
#nav li ul li a:hover, #nav li ul:not(:hover) li.active a {
    background-color: #e15a1f;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 62.5em)
/* 1000 */
 {
    #nav {
        width: 100%;
        position: static;
        margin: 0;
    }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 40em)
/* 640 */
 {
    html {
        font-size: 75%;
        /* 12 */
    }
    #nav {
        position: relative;
        top: auto;
        left: auto;
    }
   /* ENTER YOUR TEXT INBETWEEN THE CONTENT: "" */
    #nav:before {
        content:"TEXT HERE";
        position: absolute;
        left: 3.5em;
        top: 50%;
        transform: translateY(-50%);
    }
    #nav > a {
        width: 3.125em;
        /* 50 */
        height: 3.125em;
        /* 50 */
        text-align: left;
        text-indent: -9999px;
        background-color: #e15a1f;
        position: relative;
    }
    #nav > a:before, #nav > a:after {
        position: absolute;
        border: 2px solid #fff;
        top: 35%;
        left: 25%;
        right: 25%;
        content:'';
    }
    #nav > a:after {
        top: 60%;
    }
    #nav:not(:target) > a:first-of-type, #nav:target > a:last-of-type {
        display: block;
    }
    /* first level */
    #nav > ul {
        height: auto;
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
    }
    #nav:target > ul {
        display: block;
    }
    #nav > ul > li {
        width: 100%;
        float: none;
    }
    #nav > ul > li > a {
        height: auto;
        text-align: left;
        padding: 0 0.833em;
        /* 20 (24) */
    }
    #nav > ul > li:not(:last-child) > a {
        border-right: none;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #cc470d;
    }
    /* second level */
    #nav li ul {
        position: static;
        padding: 1.25em;
        /* 20 */
        padding-top: 0;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav id="nav" role="navigation"> <a href="#nav" title="Show navigation">Show navigation</a>
 <a href="#" title="Hide navigation">Hide navigation</a>

    <ul class="clearfix">
        <li><a href="http://www.google.co.uk" target="new">Item 1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 2</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 3</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 4</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 5</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Welcome mate, this doesn't require any extra html markup which is a bonus. ;)